# Http404 error while click the submit button (Servlet question)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Guys! I am new to servlet. I tried to follow the step with book to create a servlet. It's just a login form where user enter the userid and password click the login, it should then display the input value in webpage. However, when I enter the userId and password, I get Http404 error.

I was wondering something maybe wrong with context.xml but I am not sure.
I also tried to mapping the servlet in xml, but still get the error.

here is my html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

   <html>
     <head>
      <title>USER LOGIN</title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-     scale=1.0">
   </head>
    <body>
       <form action="UserServlet" method="get">
         <!-- Name text Field -->
         <p>
            <label>User ID</label>
            <input type ="text" name="userId" size="30"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>User Password</label>
            <input type ="text" name="userPassword" size="30"/>
        </p>       

        <!--Button for submit -->
         <input type ="submit" name="Login" value="LogIn"/>

            <input type ="button" value="LogOut" onclick="self.close()"/>


      </form>
  </body>
```

here is my servlet.java

```
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet
{



//process the HTTP GET REQUEST//

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();


    //get the data
    String userId=request.getParameter("userId");
    String passWord=request.getParameter("userPassWord");

    //determine the input if user missing these two send back the message
    if (userId.isEmpty()&&passWord.isEmpty()) 
    {
        out.println("UserId and passWord can not be empty.");
    }

    else
    {
        out.println("<p>your id is "+userId);
        out.println("<br>your password is"+passWord);
        out.println("<br>You entered the  data successfully </p>");



    }


}
}
```

here is my context.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Context path="/userLogin"/>
```

I didn't change any thing in context.xml

its working when I run the project, but once I click the button it just gives me

Type Status Report

Message /userLogin/UserServlet

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Comment: post you web.xml

Comment: Why would you submit a form using `get`??

Comment: I only have context.xml when I create the web application in netbeans, the context.xml is the only one I have

Comment: use [WebServlet](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) , in your `Servlet` class.

Comment: @Swati what's the issue of using httpServlet?

Comment: @ScaryWombat. do I really need to have web.xml in order to be able to run the submit button?

Comment: can you add  `@WebServlet("/UserServlet" )`above the  `public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet `

Comment: @JimmyChen either that or WebServlet annotation

Comment: @JimmyChen if you use that,you don't need `web.xml` ,[here](https://www.javatpoint.com/servlet-with-annotation) are some good tutorial and more info about it.

Comment: @Swati thank you! It finally works.  But I am wondering what the context.xml uses for?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23147836/explanation-of-context-xml) for detail explanation .

Answer (score 0):

can you check what is the servlet mapping provided in web.xml. I think the mapping would not be matching the request.
or you can post the web.xml

Comment: I only have default context.xml, when I create the web application in netbeans.  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Context path="/userLogin"/>